# Render a different component inside a div when Link is clicked "react-router-dom" v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to render a component inside my dashboard component by clicking a Link in that component,
I need to render Home or Contacts or About component inside my div
should I use array to store the components I want to render or route? adn how do I do it?

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import Contacts from "./Contacts";

const DashBoard = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <div>
        <div> // this is my side nav
          <Route>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/dashboard/home">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Issues</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Contacts</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/dashBoard/about">About</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </Route>
      </div>

      <div>
        <nav>
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            id="menu-toggle"
            onClick={() => setIsToggled(!isToggled)}
          >
            Toggle Menu
          </button>
        </nav>

        <div className="container-fluid">
        // i need to render a component here ex.) <Home/> | <Contacts/> | <About/> when a Link is clicked!
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashBoard;
```

in my app.js

```
<Fragment>
  <Navbar />
    <div className="">
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/dashBoard" component={DashBoard} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Does the path change when the link is clicked? You can use another `<Switch>` inside your component.

Comment: First, you don't need `<Route>` component in Dashboard component. Second, you defined route with exact params, it means, that only on exactly the same  `/dashBoard` url it will render your component. You need to remove exact or add additional route or use exactly the same `Link to` property as defined in switch route path.

Comment: i resolve the problem using switch inside the div then add routes to each component that i want to render tnx @RossAllen, and yes putting ```<Route>``` is not needed then removed the ```exact`` @demkovych